# On home page remove link from logo

Tags: homepage, logo

I'd like to remove the link that is generated around the logo when users are on the home page. Does wordpress have a built in function so I can wrap an if condition around the logo in the template so if the current page is the home page I can have the output without the a tag, and the else would simply be the current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a template specific thing mate. You might have to edit the `header.php` and add a condition like:

```
<?php

//Check for homepage
if(!is_front_page())
{
    //The link around logo markup
}
else
{
    //Just the logo markup without the link
}

?>
```